# Show active links in SharePoint 2013 search results

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, search-results

I'm working on SharePoint 2013 search.
I'm trying show results from a list.
The list has fields which are multiline and can have HTML attributes.
I am able to show search results from this field.
But I have some links in those feilds. But this links are not shown in the search summary.
Is there any way to show the link also with the search result and the user able to click on it and go to corresponding target. Now the user need to click on the item title and it will take to veiw properties page and then the user needs to click on the link and go.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new Display Template for that content type so that you can add the full HTML of the field in the result. You could also create a hoverpanel for the Content type to display the HTML, it's up to you.

1. Create a Managed Property for the field with the HTML, if it doesn't exist.
2. Copy an existing Display Template and add your Managed Property to it.
3. Decide where you want your value to be rendered and insert it into the template
4. Create a Result Type Rule to display your template.

I cover all these steps in detail here: http://www.ableblue.com/blog/archive/2013/06/05/introduction-to-sharepoint-2013-display-templates/